# Batch script to copy folder structure with files skip specific sub-folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to copy a folder structure with all data but need to skip folders who have named as 'others'. I created `.bat` file and trying to move source to destination. I used `xcopy /e` and `exist` to check folder but I can't make it. How can I do it?

Comment: Just try `xcopy /?` and pay your attention to `/EXCLUDE` switch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `robocopy /E /XD <exclude_file>`. See `robocopy /?` for more options.

Answer (score 0):

create a `exclude.txt` list into which you can specify which folders or sub folders you want to skip. 
use

```
xcopy "source" "destination" /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt
```